# How does perl resolve possible hash collisions in hashes?

Tags: perl, hashmap

As we know, perl implements its 'hash' type as a table with calculated indexes, where these indexes are truncated hashes.

As we also know, a hashing function can (and will, by probability) collide, giving the same hash to 2 or more different inputs.

**Then**: How does the perl interpreter handle when it finds that a key generated the same hash than another key? Does it handle it at all?

**Note**: This is not about the algorithm for hashing but about collision resolution in a hash table implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What hashing function/algorithm does Perl use ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214270/what-hashing-function-algorithm-does-perl-use)

Comment: @MattJacob this is a different matter. I don't care about the algorithm. I want to know how does it resolve the hashing collisions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Perl hash is an array of linked lists.

```
+--------+       +--------+
|       -------->|        |
+--------+       +--------+
|        |       | key1   |
+--------+       +--------+
|      ------+   | val1   |
+--------+   |   +--------+
|        |   |
+--------+   |   +--------+     +--------+
             +-->|       ------>|        |
                 +--------+     +--------+
                 | key2   |     | key3   |
                 +--------+     +--------+
                 | val2   |     | val3   |
                 +--------+     +--------+
```

The hashing function produces a value which is used as the array index, then a linear search of the associated linked list is performed.

This means the worse case to lookup is O(N). So why do people say it's O(1)? You could claim that if you kept the list from exceeding some constant length, and that's what Perl does. It uses two mechanisms to achieve this:

- Increasing the number of buckets.
- Hashing algorithm perturbing.

Doubling the number of buckets should divide the number of entries in a given by half, on average. For example,

```
305419896 % 4 = 0 and 943086900 % 4 = 0
305419896 % 8 = 0 and 943086900 % 8 = 4
```

However, a malicious actor could choose values where this doesn't happen. This is where the hash perturbation comes into play. Each hash has its own random number that perturbs (causes variances in) the output of the hashing algorithm. Since the attacker can't predict the random number, they can't choose values that will cause collisions. When needed, Perl can rebuild the hash using a new random number, causing keys to map to different buckets than before, and thus breaking down long chains.

Comment: It’s a separate chaining with linked lists then. That triggers 2 more questions: is that random a salt? And I get perl starts with a small table, growing it then, so I guess it masks the hash down, then collisions will be more. Does it grow the table by number of buckets occupied or by convenience? Maybe this deserves another question, and a probabilistic study to understand the choice.

Comment: You could call it a salt, yeah. /// it doubles the number of buckets

Comment: I get it doubles the number (it stops masking a bit). But when does it say: "ok, let's grow the table up"? Does it just count the number of occupied buckets (vs allocated) or is it some other sort of thing?

Comment: Surely yes, but also when a chain gets too long.

Comment: I think this commit in the perl repo is enough: [commit](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/05f97de032fe95cabe8c9f6d6c0a5897b1616194). Thanks.

Comment: It doubles [when there is a collision and the "load factor" is 2/3](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/hv.c#l37)

Answer (score 2):

Sets of key-value pairs where the keys produce the same hash value are stored together in a linked list. The gory details are available in [`hv.c`](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/hv.c#l837).